# Why part is missing and some parts are created in Roblox Studio?

Tags: error-handling, lua, roblox, luau

I made a script that generate stars with accurate Position but, when i click play some parts was missing other created, when i click Test the all part created successfully. In script output i dont see any error.
How to fix this? This make me insane.

Script in Serverscriptservice

```
local sun = Instance.new("Part")
sun.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
sun.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 0.2)
sun.Parent = workspace
sun.Position = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
sun.Anchored = true
sun.Name = "Sun"

function starmap(RA_h, RA_m, RA_s, Dec_deg, Dec_m, Dec_s, Distance, apparent, startype, name)   
    local A = math.rad((RA_h * 15) + (RA_m * 15)/60 + (RA_s * 15)/3600)
    local B = math.rad((Dec_deg) + (Dec_m / 60) + (Dec_s / 3600))
    local C = (Distance * 3.26) / 2-- convert ly to parsecs
    -- Cartesian converter
    local X_car = (C * math.cos(B)) * math.cos(A)
    local Y_car = (C * math.cos(B)) * math.sin(A)
    local Z_car = C * math.sin(B)
    
    --Create a star and location
    local star = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
    star.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
    star.Position = Vector3.new(X_car, Y_car, Z_car)
    star.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
    star.Anchored = true
    star.Name = name
    star.Size = Vector3.new(10,10, 10)
    star.Archivable = true
    star.CanCollide = true
    star:SetAttribute("Namer", name)
    
    -- Star class type identifier
    if startype == "O" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(155, 176, 255)
    elseif startype == "B" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(156, 178, 255)
    elseif startype == "A" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(185, 201, 255)
    elseif startype == "F" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(224, 229, 255)
    elseif startype == "G" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 248, 252)
    elseif startype == "K" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 238, 221)
    elseif startype == "M" then
        star.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 195, 139)
    end
    

    local M = apparent - 5 * math.log10((Distance / 3.26) / 10 )
    
    local x = 2.512^(4.83 - apparent) 
    star.Size = Vector3.new(x, x, x)
    
    if star.Size.X <= 0.05 and star.Size.Y <= 0.05 and star.Size.Z <= 0.05 then
        star.Size = Vector3.new(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
    end
    
    if star.Size.X >= 5 and star.Size.Y >= 5 and star.Size.Z >= 5 then
        star.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 2)
    end
    
    if C <= 50 then
        star.Size = Vector3.new(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
    end
    
    
end

if not game.Workspace:FindFirstChild("Alnitak A") then
    print("Star missing!!")
end

-------------------------------------------------------------SET OF STARS FROM INTERNET --------------------------------------------
-- LIMIT : ONE THOUSAND STARS AND 100 DEEP SKY OBJECTS PUT IN THE STAR ARCHIVE MORE THAN ONE THOUSANDS MIGHT CAUSE LAG OR NOT RECOMMEND ONE THOUSAND

-- MOBILE = 1000
-- LAPTOP = 50000
-- PC = 100000

--------------------------------------- SOUTHERN CRUX STAR PACKAGE ----------------------------------------------
wait(1)
starmap(12, 47, 43.32, -59, -41, -19.4, 352, 1.25, "B", "Mimosa")
starmap(12, 26, 35.94, -63,- 05, -56.6, 321, 1.4, "B", "Acrux")
starmap(12, 31, 9.93, -57, -6, -45.2, 88, 1.60, "M", "Gacrux")
starmap(12, 15, 8.71673, -58, -44, -56.1369, 345, 2.78, "B", "Imai")

------------------------------------------ ORION STAR PACKAGES -----------------------------------------------

starmap(05, 14, 32.27,  -08, -12, -05.9, 773, 0.18, "B", "Rigel")
starmap(05, 55, 10.29,  07, 24, 25.3, 643, 0.42, "M", "Betelgeuse")
starmap(05, 25, 07.87,  06, 20, 59.0, 242, 1.64, "B", "Bellatrix")
starmap(05, 36, 12.81,  -01, -12, -06.9, 1342, 1,69, "B", "Alnilam")
starmap(05, 40, 45.52,  -01, -56, -33.3, 817, 1.88, "O", "Alnitak A")
starmap(05, 47, 45.39,  -09, 40, 10.6, 721, 2.07, "B", "Saiph")
starmap(05, 32, 00.40,  -00, -17, -56.7, 916, 2.20, "B", "Mintaka AB")
starmap(05, 35, 25.98,  -05, -54, -35.6, 1325, 2.75, "O", "Iota Orionis")

--------------------------------------------TAURUS STAR PACKAGES---------------------------------------
wait(1)
starmap(04, 35, 55.20,  16, 30, 35.1, 65, 0.87, "K", "Aldebaran")
starmap(05, 26, 17.50,  28, 36, 28.3, 131, 1.65, "B", "Beta Tauri")
starmap(03, 47, 29.06,  24, 06, 18.9, 368, 2.85, "B", "Alcycone A")
starmap(05, 37, 38.68,  21, 08, 33.3, 417, 2.97, "B", "Zeta Tauri")
starmap(04, 28, 39.67,  15, 52, 15.4, 148, 3.40, "A", "Theta_2 Tauri")
starmap(04, 00, 40.82,  12, 29, 25.4, 370, 3.41, "B", "Lambda Tauri")
starmap(04, 28, 36.93,  19, 10, 49.9, 155, 3.53, "K", "Epsilon Tauri")
starmap(03, 24, 48.84,  09, 01, 44.6, 211, 3.61, "G", "Omicron Tauri")
starmap(03, 49, 09.73,  24, 03, 12.7, 380, 3.62, "B", "Atlas A")
starmap(04, 19, 47.53,  15, 37, 39.7, 154, 3.65, "G", "Gamma Tauri")
starmap(03, 44, 52.52,  24, 06, 48.4, 370, 3.72, "B", "Electra")
starmap(03, 27, 10.12,  09, 43, 58.0, 222, 3.73, "B", "Xi Tauri")
starmap(04, 22, 56.03,  17, 32, 33.3, 153, 3.77, "G", "Delta_1 Tauri")
starmap(04, 28, 34.43,  15, 57, 44.0, 158, 3.84, "G", "Theta Tauri")
starmap(03, 45, 49.59,  24, 22, 04.3, 360, 3.87, "B", "Maia")
starmap(04, 03, 09.38,  05, 59, 21.5, 129, 3.91, "A", "Nu Tauri")
starmap(03, 30, 52.37,  12, 56, 12.1, 360, 4.14, "K", "5 Tauri")
starmap(03, 46, 19.56,  23, 56, 54.5, 359, 4.14, "B", "Merope")
starmap(04, 25, 22.10,  22, 17, 38.3, 153, 4.21, "A", "Kappa Tauri")
starmap(04, 35, 39.23,  10, 09, 39.3, 150, 4.25, "A", "88 Tauri")
starmap(04, 15, 32.05,  08, 53, 32.7, 435, 4.27, "B", "Mu Tauri")

------------------------------------------CASSIOPEIA STAR PACKAGES------------------------------------------

starmap(00, 40, 30.39,  56, 32, 14.7, 228, 2.24, "K", "Schedar")
starmap(00, 09, 10.09,  59, 09, 00.8, 54, 2.28, "B", "Caph")
starmap(00, 09, 10.09,  59, 09, 00.8, 613, 2.47, "B", "Gamma Cassiopeiae")
starmap(01, 25, 48.60,  60, 14, 07.5, 99, 2.68, "A", "Delta Cassiopeiae")
starmap(01, 54, 23.68,  63, 40, 12.5, 442, 3.35, "B", "Epsilon Cassiopeiae")
starmap(00, 49, 05.10,  57, 48, 59.6, 19, 3.46, "G", "Eta Cassiopeiae")
starmap(00, 36, 58.27,  53, 53, 49.0, 597, 3.69, "B", "Zeta Cassiopeiae")
starmap(02, 03, 26.19,  72, 25, 16.5, 162, 3.95, "A", "50 Cassiopeiae")
starmap(00, 32, 59.99,  62, 55, 54.4, 4127, 4.17, "B", "Kappa Cassiopeiae")
starmap(01, 11, 05.93,  55, 08, 59.8, 137, 4.34, "A", "Theta Cassiopeiae")
starmap(02, 29, 03.99,  67, 24, 08.6, 141, 4.46, "A", "Iota Cassiopeiae")
starmap(00, 44, 43.50,  48, 17, 03.8, 906, 4.48, "B", "Omicron Cassiopeiae")
starmap(02, 01, 57.55,  70, 54, 25.4, 117, 4.49, "A", "48 Cassiopeiae")

-------------------------------------------CANCER STAR PACKAGES------------------------------------------------
wait(1)
starmap(08, 16, 30.95,  09, 11, 08.4, 240, 3.53, "K", "Beta Cancri / Tarf")
starmap(08, 44, 41.11,  18, 09, 17.5, 136, 3.94, "K", "Delta Cancri / Asellus Australis")
starmap(08, 46, 41.83,  28, 45, 36.0, 293, 4.03, "G", "Delta Cancri")
starmap(08, 58, 29.20,  11, 51, 28.0, 173, 4.26, "A", "Acubens / Sertans / Alpha Cancri"    )
starmap(08, 43, 17.21,  21, 28, 06.9, 181, 4.66, "A", "Gamma Cancri / Asellus Borealis")
starmap(08, 12, 12.71,  17, 38, 53.3, 83, 4.67, "G", "Tegmine / Zeta Cancri")
starmap(08, 25, 54.79,  07, 33, 52.3, 359, 5.13, "G", "HD 71115")
starmap(08, 05, 04.51,  13, 07, 06.1, 210, 5.14, "A", "8 Cancri")
starmap(08, 20, 03.87,  27, 13, 07.0, 59, 5.14, "F", "Chi Cancri")
starmap(09, 09, 21.53,  22, 02, 43.6, 380, 5.16, "K", "Xi Cancri / Nahn")
starmap(08, 57, 14.91,  15, 19, 21.8, 160, 5.22, "A", "Omicron_2 Cancri")
starmap(08, 55, 39.69,  27, 55, 39.2, 574, 5.23, "G", "Rho_2 Cancri")
starmap(08, 59, 32.68,  32, 25, 07.1, 320, 5.23, "G", "Sigma_3 Cancri")

-------------------------------------------SCORPIUS STAR PACKAGES--------------------------------------

starmap(16, 29, 24.47,  -26, -25, -55.0, 553, 0.91, "M", "Antares A" )
starmap(17, 33, 36.53,  -37, -06, -13.5, 1.62, 703, "B", "Lambda Scorpii")
starmap(17, 37, 19.13,  -42, -59, -52.2, 272, 1.86, "F", "Theta Scorpii")
starmap(16, 00, 20.01,  -22, -37, -17.8, 401, 2.29, "B", "Delta Scorpii"    )
starmap(16, 50, 10.24,  -34, -17, -33.4, 65, 2.29, "K", "Epsilon Scorpii")
starmap(17, 42, 29.28,  -39, -01, -47.7, 464, 2.39, "B", "Kappa Scorpii")
starmap(16, 05, 26.23,  -19, -48, -19.4, 530, 2.62, "B", "Beta_1 Scorpii "  )
starmap(17, 30, 45.84,  -37, -17, -44.7, 518, 2.70, "B", "Upsilon Scorpii")
starmap(15, 58, 51.12,  -26, -06, -50.6, 459, 2.89, "B", "Tau Scorpii")
starmap(16, 21, 11.32,  -25, -35, -33.9, 734, 2.90, "B", "Sigma Scorpii")
starmap(17, 47, 35.08,  -40, -07, -37.1, 1791, 2.99, "F", "Iota_1 Scorpii")
starmap(16, 51, 52.24,  -38, -02, -50.4, 821, 3.00, "B", "Mu_1 Scorpii")
starmap(17, 49, 51.45,  -37, -02, -36.1, 127, 3.19, "K", "G Scorpii")
starmap(17, 12, 09.18,  -43, -14, -18.6, -72, 3.32, "F", "Eta Scorpii")
starmap(16, 52, 20.15,  -38, -01, -02.9, 517, 3.56, "B", "Mu_2 Scorpii")
starmap(16, 54, 35.11,  -42, -21, -38.7, 150, 3.62, "K", "Zeta_2 Scorpii")
starmap(15, 56, 53.09,  -29, -12, -50.4, 409, 3.82, "B", "Rho Scorpii")

----------------------------------------- AURIGA STAR PACKAGES --------------------------------------------

starmap(05, 16, 41.30,  45, 59, 56.5, 42, 0.08, "G", "Capella")
starmap(05, 59, 31.77,  44, 56, 50.8, 82, 1.90, "A", "Beta Aurigae")
starmap(05, 59, 43.24,  37, 12, 46.0, 173, 2.62, "A", "Theta Aurigae")
starmap(04, 56, 59.62,  33, 09, 58.1, 512, 2.69, "K", "Iota Aurigae")
starmap(05, 01, 58.13,  43, 49, 23.9, 2037, 3.03, "F", "Epsilon Aurigae")
starmap(05, 06, 30.87,  41, 14, 04.7, 219, 3.18, "B", "Eta Aurigae")
starmap(05, 02, 28.68,  41, 04, 33.2, 787, 3.69, "K", "Zeta Aurigae")
starmap(05, 59, 31.55,  54, 17, 05.9, 140, 3.72, "K", "Delta Aurigae")
starmap(05, 51, 29.39,  39, 08, 54.5, 215, 3.97, "K", "Nu Aurigae")
starmap(05, 59, 56.10,  45, 56, 12.3, 840, 4.30, "M", "Pi Aurigae")
starmap(06, 15, 22.74,  29, 29, 55.4, 169, 4.32, "G", "Kappa Aurigae")
starmap(05, 49, 10.46,  39, 10, 52.1, 213, 4.51, "G", "Tau Aurigae")

---------------------------------------- CORONA BOREALIS PACKAGES --------------------------------------

starmap(15, 34, 41.19,  26, 42, 53.7, 75, 2.22, "A", "Alpha Coronae Borealis")
starmap(15, 27, 49.85,  29, 06, 19.8, 114, 3.66, "F", "Beta Coronae Borealis")
starmap(15, 42, 44.64,  26, 17, 43.9, 145, 3.81, "A", "Gamma Coronae Borealis")
starmap(15, 32, 55.80,  31, 21, 33.0, 311, 4.14, "B", "Theta Coronae Borealis")
starmap(15, 57, 35.30,  26, 52, 40.9, 230, 4.14, "K", "Epsilon Coronae Borealis")
starmap(16, 01, 26.59,  29, 51, 03.9, 341, 4.98, "A", "Iota Coronae Borealis")
starmap(15, 49, 35.70,  26, 04, 06.8, 165, 4.59, "G", "Delta Coronae Borealis")

------------------------------------------ LYRA STAR PACKAGES ----------------------------------------------------

starmap(18, 36, 56.19,  38, 46, 58.8, 25, 0.03, "A", "Vega")
starmap(18, 58, 56.62,  32, 41, 22.4, 634, 3.25, "B", "Gamma Lyrae")
starmap(18, 50, 04.79,  33, 21, 45.6, 881, 3.52, "A", "Beta Lyrae A")
starmap(18, 55, 20.09,  43, 56, 45.2, 349, 4.08, "M", "R Lyrae")
starmap(18, 54, 30.29,  36, 53, 55.0, 398, 4.22, "M", "Delta Lyrae")
starmap(18, 19, 51.72,  36, 03, 52.0, 238, 4.33, "K", "Kappa Lyrae")
starmap(18, 44, 46.34,  37, 36, 18.2, 154, 4.34, "A", "Zeta_1 Lyrae")
```

I tried to rewrite the script but the problem is still here, i expecting to working but isnt working the result is still same!! How to fix this?

Comment: Are there specific parts that always disappear? Or is it always randomly different parts that disappear?

Comment: There is some specific parts disappear when i click play, but the specific parts work properly when i click run.

Comment: I think it has to do with the height those specific stars are placed at, can you confirm for me that all the specific starts that disappear are at least below Y=0?

Comment: No, some dissapeared stars are above the Y=0 axis.

Comment: @Ivan, It didn't work for me

Comment: Nevermind it works now yay

Comment: Nice, what was the actual solution?